# UIView is not being removed

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, uiimage

I need to display different size of a UIImage depending on the UIInterfaceOrientation. Now the problem is, everytime the program changes its orientation the image is still there and the new one is overlapping it. Here's what I have

```
UIView *logoView;

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[logoView removeFromSuperview];
CGRect rect;
UIInterfaceOrientation newOrientation =  [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
if(newOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || newOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
{
    rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width/2, self.view.bounds.size.height/4);
    logoView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.bounds.size.width/2, self.view.bounds.size.height/4)];
}

else if (newOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || newOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
{
    rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height/4);
    logoView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height/4)];
}
imageView.frame = logoView.bounds;
[logoView addSubview:imageView];


[self.view addSubview:logoView];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `logoView` is a local variable. so [`logoView removeFromSuperview]` will not working.

Make `logoView` a **Property** or a **class variable** will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

create global logoView

if it is not null remove it from superview

```
    if(logoView){

    [logoView removeFromSuperview];
logoView = nil;
    }
```

and if it is null then only intialize it

```
if(newOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || newOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
{
    rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width/2, self.view.bounds.size.height/4);
if(!logoView){
    logoView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.bounds.size.width/2, self.view.bounds.size.height/4)];
}
}




else if (newOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || newOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
{
    rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height/4);
if(!logoView){
    logoView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height/4)];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`[logoView removeFromSuperview];` doesn't remove the old logoView.In fact, if you do not keep the logoView as a property in your controller, you will not get the logoView and remove it from `self.view`.

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *logoView;//You can keep it and get it when you want to remove it.

@end
```

Then:

```
[self.logoView removeFromSuperview];//get the logoView and remove it.
UIView *logoView;

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

CGRect rect;
UIInterfaceOrientation newOrientation =  [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
if(newOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || newOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
    rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width/2, self.view.bounds.size.height/4);
    logoView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.bounds.size.width/2, self.view.bounds.size.height/4)];
} else if (newOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || newOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
    rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height/4);
    logoView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height/4)];
}
imageView.frame = logoView.bounds;

self.logoView = logoView;//keep logoView

[logoView addSubview:imageView];

[self.view addSubview:logoView];//add logoView to self.view
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the Tag to remove the UIView. I hope it will useful for you

```
 logoView.tag = 108;  //set the tag
 [[self.view viewWithTag:108]removeFromSuperview];   //remove the view the superview
```

OR assign the variable to public "logoView"